# Meaning of the phrase "to name a few"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is meaning of the phrase "to name a few" in below sentence:

> Our clients include Commonwealth Bank, Lexus, Tourism Australia to name a few

I rarely see this phrase, so I think there's an alternative for its meaning. Could some one can show me one?

Comment: Probably, since they already said *include*, they could omit *to name a few* and still keep the same meaning.

Comment: GEdgar: grammatically yes, but the point is that they have many more (and so you should be impressed), whereas a weasel-run company would use the phrase even if they had only three customers. (I find *to name a few* a good indicator of weasels, but that's another question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility here would be *among others*:

> Our clients include Commonwealth Bank, Lexus, and Tourism Australia, among others.

Answer (score 14):

The expression "to name a few" is used when there are lot of things to list. But you prefer the best one or the ones you like to list because there are so many choices available.

Another meaning is "There are more examples also."

Ex.The dealsforyou website has so many products like clothes, electronics, food, vegetables, just to name a few.

Comment: Is there a substitution for the phrase it that sentences?

Comment: We can use "to verify" as a substitution for phrase it that sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It means pretty well the same as "for example".